# Do I need a special cable for this SSD?

Tags: cable, usb-c

I just bought a [SanDisk 2 Tb SSD](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1730628-REG/sandisk_sdssde30_2t00_g25_e30_2tb_portable_ssd.html). It's amazing that I can carry so much data in such a tiny package for just $120.

The device has a USB-C port, but SanDisk assumes that my computer has the older USB-A because the device comes only with a USB-C to A cable. But my [ThinkPad Z-16](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpadz/thinkpad-z16-(16-inch-amd)/21d4000hus) has only USB-C ports. I have adapters from A to C to connect my old USB-A devices, but I'd like to connect the SSD directly to the computer instead of going C-A-C to connect it.

My question is, do I need any kind of special cable for this connection, or can I just use any USB-C to C cable from Amazon or Best Buy?

Comment: Many cables are intended for charging and trivial data transfer only, that is, they are USB 2.0 cables. Confirm that it is a 5/10/20Gbps cable depending on your devices' (including your hosts) capabilities / your need. (The story of so-called "40Gbps cables" is more "complicated", AFAIK; I mean they could turn out to be effectively 20Gbps.) You can use a slower cable as long as you don't mind though. (Also note that Gbps is not GB/s. Do the math before you think "I don't need such high speed".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware that most cables these days only support USB 2.0 data no matter what the end connectors are.  Maximum transfer speed requires a USB C 3.2 cable--you will pay more for this than for a 2.0 cable and the length limits are a lot shorter.