# How can this USB connection be direction-dependent?

Tags: usb

This is a follow up to my previous question, [*Do I need a special cable for this SSD?*](https://superuser.com/questions/1777260/do-i-need-a-special-cable-for-this-ssd).

To summarize the situation in that question: I bought an SSD to use with my computer. The SSD and computer both have USB-C ports and no USB-A ports, but the SSD came with a cable for connecting USB-C to USB-A. So I have to either get a USB C-to-C cable or use a USB C-to-A adapter cable.

I have not yet obtained a C-to-C cable, but today I was testing some cables that I have on hand, and something mysterious is happening.

There are four cables involved:

- Two USB-A male to USB-C male. One came with the SSD. The other came as part of a phone charger.
- Two [USB-C male to USB-A female](https://www.insigniaproducts.com/pdp/NS-PU396CA-WH/8896017) that I bought at BestBuy some time ago for connecting USB-A devices to the USB-C ports on my previous computer.

Today, I tested the ability to use a combination of one cable from each of the above two categories. When I first tried it, the computer did not respond when I plugged in the SSD. After switching out cables to see if one was defective, I finally also tried reversing the direction of the connection. Then, for the first time, the computer responded to the SSD and accessed it successfully.

I have found that the following connection works:

> Computer - (USB-C male to USB-A female) - (USB-A male to USB-C male) - SSD

and the following does not work:

> Computer - (USB-C male to USB-A male) - (USB-A female to USB-C male) - SSD

Those two connections are identical, except for the direction of the cables between the SSD and the computer. I have tested multiple cable pairs, switching out the different cables of the same type, and always get the same result based on directionality of the connection.

I would not have expected a USB connection to be direction-dependent. I [Googled "USB direction"](https://www.google.com/search?q=USB%20direction) and the only relevant result was a [question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Do-USB-cables-go-in-one-direction-only) with some differing opinions about whether USB connections are direction-dependent. One answer even said that using the wrong direction could cause hardware damage. But none of the answers that said direction matters offered an explanation of why, nor of how to know which direction will work. There are other Google results that talk about direction dependence, but what they mean is dependence on the orientation of the plug in the socket, not the direction the cable is facing. There is also something called "USB redirection," which is something entirely unrelated.

What could be going on here that is causing the direction dependence of this connection?

Comment: "I would not have expected a USB connection to be direction-dependent." - It's not;  There is another reason for it not working.  I just can't determine that since I know nothing about the cables you had on hand.

Comment: @Ramhound - I've edited the question with a link to the specific product for one set of the cables. Can you give one or more examples of the sorts of things that could cause the issue if you knew more about the cables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type-C connectors have [more pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#USB-C_receptacle_pin_usage_in_different_modes) than type-A/B connectors do (even more than the extended USB3 connectors), so you cannot actually have an end-to-end type-C connection if it's coupled through type-A ports.

More importantly, some of those pins are specifically for identifying the *type of cable*, which will report different results for cables with "type-A male" vs "type-A female" connector on the other end (and different again for a C-to-C cable).

In other words, both types of C-to-A cables are deliberately designed to add directionality in order to stay compatible with traditional USB (which always had type-A connectors go into the host/power-supply, type-B into the device/power-consumer).

As precedent, take a look at the widespread "micro-B" connector which has five pins, even though the other end (the full-size type-A) only has four. The fifth pin tells the micro-B port whether you have connected a host (type-A male cable, device supplies power) or a downstream device (type-A female cable aka "OTG cable", device receives power), so that e.g. your phone could supply power to OTG accessories without also trying to supply power to your desktop PC or your charger.

Similarly, in USB Type-C, all connectors have a pair of "CC" pins which, among other things, can be used to tell the port whether to supply power initially or not. A "type-A female" cable will include a resistor in its type-C connector to request power for the device that's connected to its type-A port, whereas a "type-A male" cable will not (as the power flows *from* the type-A side instead).

As a result, the computer's type-C port only supplies power if it recognizes a cable with "type-A female" on the other end. (If this was not the case, your "C-to-A-to-C" cable would have either both devices supplying power – and potentially frying them – or neither of them supplying power.)

Real type-C-to-C cables have no such issues as they connect the CC pins end-to-end, allowing both devices to directly negotiate power supply regardless of cable direction, but of course that doesn't happen with a type-A port in the middle. (Type-A/B ports had no such pins; the connector shape ensured that power would always flow from type-A to type-B, until the five-pin micro-B was introduced.)

See 1) the Microchip link in Daniel B's post, 2) [USB-C receptacle pin usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#USB-C_receptacle_pin_usage_in_different_modes) on Wikipedia:

> However, to connect a USB 2.0/1.1 device to a USB-C host, use of Rd[57] on the CC pins is required, as the source (host) will not supply VBUS until a connection is detected through the CC pins.
>
> This means many USB-A male to USB-C cables will only work in the A to C direction (connecting to a USB-C devices, e.g. for charging) as they do not include the termination resistors needed to work in the C to A direction (from a USB-C host). Adapters or cables from USB-C to USB-A female usually do work as they include the required termination resistor.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent, detailed answer, with reference to documentation specifically about the directionality issue.

Comment: Can you say, since the A part of the combination has fewer pins than the C part, am I losing something by using this combination of cables to connect the SSD to my computer?

Comment: Do both of the A connectors at least have the extra row of "USB 3.0" pins? If they don't, then you're definitely losing performance as the A connectors limit you to USB 2.0 speeds. Otherwise, as long as you're only using standard USB communications – *probably* not losing anything. (After all, the device did come with a basic type-A cable, it doesn't require anything like Thunderbolt passthrough.)

Answer (score 2):

I’m going to base this answer off the assumption that this description is incorrect:

> USB-C male to USB-A female that I bought at BestBuy some time ago for connecting USB-C devices to my previous computer that had only USB-A ports

USB-A female is the *receptacle* that is normally on a USB host device. There is no standards-conformant way you could use an adapter like this to connect USB-C devices to a host that only has USB-A connectors. (USB-A to USB-A cables are “illegal”. Only USB-A to USB-B is valid.)

This adapter is precisely for the use case that works for you: To connect a USB-A device to a USB-C host. (Nevermind that on the other end it’s again USB-C.)

USB-C (in general) is not at all bidirectional. This is because USB-C supports so many modes of operation. The cable must specify what it can do. The adapter does this. The other cable does not, because the device it is for probably doesn’t care and always works in “plain USB” mode.

---

Microchip has [a great document on implementing USB-C in devices](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00001914B.pdf) (not hosts). It’s how your USB-C (male) to USB-A (female) adapter would work internally.

Comment: You are right about the error in that description, and I've corrected it in the question.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, especially when you say that USB-C is "not at all bidirectional." If that's so and I get a USB-C to USB-C cable, would it tell me which direction I can use it to connect a device to my computer? No, presumably it would work in either direction. So why doesn't the combination of two cables that, put together, become a USB-C to USB-C cable work in either direction?

Comment: If that Microchip document explains or states that USB-C is not bidirectional, can you say where in the document to find that? I searched in it for "direction", and it's not there.

Comment: @NewSites: They don't become a C-to-C cable because of 1) the additional pins that type-C connectors have which type-A/B connectors do not, and therefore aren't passed through end-to-end, 2) resistors inside type-C connectors that allow them to determine the cable type (e.g. to make sure the type-C port will not supply power to cables that have a male type-A on the other end, frying the device).

Comment: @user1686 - Interesting. It sounds like your comment might be the answer to my question. Do you want to post it as such? And can you say, based on this, am I losing something by using this combination to connect the SSD to my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Something they never teach you in biology class… ***sex is not important*** …when it comes to USB;)
USB, prior to USB-C, is extremely 'directional' insomuch that plugs for each 'direction' are not different sexes, but actually completely different designs, so you can never get them the wrong way round.

USB  has a host > device structure that cannot be reversed. Any USB cable with male one end & the same plug but female the other end is an *extender*.

USB-C changed this to a more 'intelligent' design, so devices could negotiate their place in the hierarchy, rather than depend on plug shape.

There's far too much detail to cover here, see [Wikipedia - USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)